# Setting More than 100 Object having different Values

Tags: java, web-services, getter-setter

I am working on a legacy project, where we are consuming a SOAP service, that service requires lots of Field Value to be set at our end before we can send it to the JAXB object.
At the moment we are doing it via setter method as shown below -

100 such label needs to be set,

```
    FieldValue field1 = new FieldValue(); // field value
    field1.setFieldName("FieldLabel1");
    field1.setValue(fileValue);
    lstfield.add(field1);

    FieldValue field2 = new FieldValue(); // Action date in format 12-Feb-14
    field2.setFieldName("FieldLabel2");
    field2.setValue(DateUtill.getCurrentdate());
    lstfield.add(field2);
```

Setting 100 FieldValue objects would be cumbersome for maintainance, if incase the webservice provider changes any label name it would be very hectic to find and change the label name.

Another way to set is using a constructor but that doesn't seem to be right option.
I was looking if there is any another way to do the above mentioned task that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 100 `FieldValue` objects and add them to a list by using for block:

```
    List<FieldValue> fieldValueList = new ArrayList<>();
    final int NUM_OF_OBJECTS = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OBJECTS; i++) {
      fieldValueList.add(new FieldValue());
    }
```

Then you can write a method in `FieldValue` class to set fieldName and value of objects:

```
  public void setFieldNameAndValue(String fieldName, Object value) {
    setFieldName(fieldName);
    setValue(value);
  }
```

and now you can set fieldName and value for each item of the generated list:

```
    fieldValueList.get(0).setFieldNameAndValue("FieldLabel1", fileValue);
    fieldValueList.get(1).setFieldNameAndValue("FieldLabel2", DateUtill.getCurrentdate());
    // set fieldName and value for remained objects
```

Another way is using Array instead of List:

```
    final int NUM_OF_OBJECTS = 100;
    FieldValue[] fieldValues = new FieldValue[NUM_OF_OBJECTS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_OBJECTS; i++) {
      fieldValues[i] = new FieldValue();
    }

    fieldValues[0].setFieldNameAndValue("FieldLabel1", fileValue);
    fieldValues[1].setFieldNameAndValue("FieldLabel2", DateUtill.getCurrentdate());
```

**UPDATED** with one more solution:
I think declaring `setFieldNameAndValue` in the `FieldValue` class is not a good way. Please forget that solution :D

```
    final int NUM_OF_OBJECTS = 100;
    final ArrayList<FieldValue> filedValueList = new ArrayList<>(NUM_OF_OBJECTS);
    addNewFieldValue(filedValueList, "fieldName1", fieldValue);
    addNewFieldValue(filedValueList, "fieldName2", DateUtill.getCurrentdate());
```

`addNewFieldValue` can be programmed like this:

```
  private static void addNewFieldValue(ArrayList<FieldValue> filedValueList, String fieldName, Object value) {
    final FieldValue fieldValue = new FieldValue();
    fieldValue.setFieldName(fieldName);
    fieldValue.setValue(value);
    filedValueList.add(fieldValue);
  }
```

Hope these lines can help you :)

Comment: Thanks, not exactly What I am going to use but I think I got the idea.

Comment: yw @Javasist. I've updated the post with another solution that may be more effiecient

Comment: Just curious the Last one can we call it that we have implemented builder pattern ??

Comment: @Javasist The builder pattern is a design pattern that allows for the step-by-step creation of complex objects using the correct sequence of actions. If you want to implement `FieldValue` class using `Builder Pattern` it's possible but too simple to use it. 

Here is a good sample for using `Builder Pattern`: [Builder Design Pattern in Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a UI class containing the fields, you can always create a static list of field names. Better still, you can create an `enum`. For example:

```
public enum Field {
    FIELD_1("FieldName1"),
    ...
    String name;
    Field(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

...

FieldValue field1 = new FieldValue(); // field value
field1.setFieldName(Field_1.getName());
field1.setValue(fileValue);
lstfield.add(field1);
```

If you want to refactor, Just change the name in this enum.

**UPDATED based on OP's Comment**
Not the ideal way, but you can create a list of value for `setValue` call and then use the following method for adding the fields:

```
public void setFields(Object[] values) {
   for (int i = 0; i < Field.values().length(); ++i) {
       final FieldValue fv = new FieldValue();
       fv.setFieldName(Field.values()[i].getName());
       fv.setValue(values[i]));
       lstField.add(fv);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but more than the value I am worried about writing the same line of code repeatedly again for 100 fields.

Comment: yeah thought of doing the same, but here I have to be very careful as the value for field1.setValue is different from : for example for FieldLabel1 fieldValue could be 1000, for FieldValue2 it could be 3000, 

So here I have to make two lists one for the Value and One for the enum values, which would be my label name. 

Against Each label, a value needs to be sent.